# SNS - Limitation in publish API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have a fundamental inquiry. The SNS publish API limit is 30,000 requests per second in the us-east-1 region. I understand that I must submit a request to augment my quota for higher TPS. Is there a maximum limit, even with a special request? If so, how do large-scale platforms managing millions of users navigate this constraint with SNS?

Comment: 30,000 requests *per second* tends to be plenty for most platforms managing "millions of users".

Comment: @ceejayoz - Can u pls explain that? Lets take Netfix as an example. When a new movie/series is launched, it has to publish notifications to all its users.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to simultaneously send a message to a large number of users when you expect those users to respond to the message by coming to your service (eg a movie site). This would cause an enormous strain on the system to handle a sudden influx of users. Systems configured with auto-scaling can handle a _gradual_ increase in the number of users but a sudden increase could lead to systems crashing due to lack of resources.

Comment: In your particular Netflix example, users are spread through the world and speak many different languages and have many different interests. It is unlikely that you would want to send a single message to "millions of users". However, 60 seconds x 30,000 requests per second is well over a million messages per minute.

Comment: I missed your comments @JohnRotenstein. I totally agree your comment for the Netflix example. However, what if I simply want to inform my customers about a completed task that doesn't require any further action on their part by coming to my service?